# Payment method not found error in razorpay in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am integrating razorpay payment method in angular 8 but when I click on pay-now button I am getting alert no appropriate payment method found anyone can help me .I used below youtube link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiJzKKjbQYI

Comment: Please provide some meaningful code (snippets) along with error messages and debug output which are describing your problem. Don't expect users to watch youtube howto video's. 

Have a look over here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using an incorrect Razorpay Key. Firstly, following is the solution:

**SOLUTION:**

```
const options = {
key: 'YOUR TEST/LIVE KEY HERE', // ---> Most important to verify and use the correct one for your purpose
amount: 100,
currency: 'INR',
name: 'My Test Payment',
... // Rest of your key-value pairs follow
}
```

**EXPLANATION:**

There are 2 ways of using an incorrect key:

1. Using a totally different Key (TEST/LIVE) that you may have generated for a totally different project.
2. Using TEST key for LIVE and LIVE key for TEST Razorpay environments.

**STEPS TO GET THE CORRECT KEY FOR YOUR SPECIFIC ENVIRONMENT:**

1. Assuming that you need the keys for the TEST environment, make sure that in Razorpay Dashboard Header, you have selected TEST mode.
2. Then visit the following link: `https://dashboard.razorpay.com/app/keys` and grab the `Key Id`.
3. In your app, use the key as shown in the **Solution** above.
4. If you want to find the LIVE keys, then start from Step 1 and make sure that in Razorpay Dashboard Header, you have selected LIVE mode.
5. Repeat Steps 2 and 3 above.
6. Lastly, if you are using a Server-side language to create the Orders as per the [Razorpay Orders API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#create-an-order) (and you should), then you need to use the correct Razorpay Key and Secret. Also make sure that you upload the server side files to the server, without which, you will continue to face the issue.

The above steps resolved the same issue for me, so I am sure you will be able to solve the issue, provided you make the correct changes at all the places where you use the API Keys and Secret.